# Why does useState react hook cause Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-hooks, jsx

I am having the following script

```
    const [setList, setSetList] = useState({ data: null });
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({ data: null });
    const [username, setUserName] = useState();
    
    const Token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    console.log(Token)
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const setlist = await axios.get(
                'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/set/list/', {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Token ${Token}`
                    }
            });
            const setuserdata = await axios.get(
                'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/current/', {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Token ${Token}`
                    }
            });
            setCurrentUser({ data: setuserdata.data });
            setSetList({ data: setlist.data });
            };
            
            fetchData();
        }, []);
        
        console.log('render');
    if (currentUser.data) {
        console.log("userdata", currentUser.data);
        console.log("userdata", currentUser.data.username);
        **setUserName(currentUser.data.username);**

    }
```

trying to call the setUserName causes the Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.. I can't seem to find the reason why.

Comment: Why don't you set the username in the UseEffect itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're calling `setUserName` *on every render*.  And setting the state triggers a re-render.  So on every render you're triggering a re-render.

If you want something to trigger when `currentUser.data` changes then don't check for it on every render, check for it in a `useEffect` hook.  For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // currentUser.data has changed, update something
}, [currentUser.data]);
```

But *in this particular case* you don't need any of this at all.  You're duplicating values in state:

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({ data: null });
const [username, setUserName] = useState();
```

Since `username` is part of `currentUser` then you don't *need* `username`, because you have `currentUser`.  Just remove the `username` state entirely and any code that's setting/using it, and refer to `currentUser.data.username` instead.

If you want to have shorthand for `username` so you don't have to write `currentUser.data` every time, then instead of tracking it in state just set a value when rendering:

```
const username = currentUser?.data?.username;
```